# What does this quote say?

Tags: grammar

For full context, see here:
https://www.docdroid.net/ipTEvqI/1.pdf

The sentence in question is from もんだい number 2, line 5-7 (おんな):
一方、妻が夫にしてほしいと思っている第1位は「**自分**が間違っていると思ったらすぐあやまってほしい」ということでした。

First, my attempt at translation:
"On the other hand, the number 1 which wifes wish their husbands to do was 'when he thinks that he himself is wrong I wish he immediately apologizes'."

Until now, when じぶん was used it usually referred to the speaker himself. However, at least in the way I understood the sentence, it wouldn't make any sense if the wifes "wished" that they themselves did X, especially not what is described here.
I suspect that the じぶん

Answer (score 2):

The gist of your understanding is correct, and your attempt at translating this is very close. Let's look at the phrase in quotation marks:

> **自分**が間違っていると思ったらすぐあやまってほしい
>   If he thinks it is **his own** mistake I would like him to apologize immediately.

In most sentences involving 自分｛じぶん｝, the subject of 自分 tends to be the speaker. However, that doesn't necessarily mean that 自分 is used only to refer to the speaker. As 自分 has the general meaning of about "one's own" or "oneself", if the subject were not the speaker but something else, then 自分 refers to "oneself" for that subject.

When the subject of the sentence is the speaker, "oneself" is "myself".

If it's someone else, "oneself" is "(his/her)self".

If it's a group of people, "oneself" is "themselves" (as a collective). For this, it's also common (if not more so) to hear 自分たち as well.